# Slicing array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

for slicing an array, we can use

```
 2.0.0p247 :021 > arr = [1,2,3,4,5] 
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
2.0.0p247 :022 > arr.each_slice(3).to_a
 => [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]] 
2.0.0p247 :034 > arr  # does not change array
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

i want to take only first part of sliced array, so i did it in the following way

```
2.0.0p247 :029 > arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
2.0.0p247 :030 > arr[0..2]
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.0.0p247 :031 > arr # does not change array
 => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

but it return a new array, and i want to do it in such a way that i can take a part of array in the same array without creating a new array
As in Ruby there are some methods of changing same array by putting a '!' sign as - sort!,reject! etc

Is there any method of doing this?

Comment: when slicing, a new object is created anyway; just test with repeated `arr[0..2].object_id` in irb, for example.  You might as well make it readable, so I'd go with Amy Hua's `arr = arr.first 3`

Answer (score 5):

Given

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

To return `array=[1,2,3]`, you can:

- Slice! off the last half, so you return the first half.

  ```
  array.slice!(3..5)
  ```
- Return the first three elements and assign it to the variable.

  ```
  array = array.first 3
  ```

  Or

  ```
  array = array[0..2]
  ```

...Or use a number of other [array methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html).

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean [`slice!` as found in the ruby docs?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice-21):

```
1.9.3p392 :001 >     ar = [1,2,3,4,5]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1.9.3p392 :002 >     ar.slice!(0,2)
=> [1, 2]
1.9.3p392 :003 > ar
=> [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: nice, but i want to take only starting part to remain in the array.so i can do it as `arr.slice!(2,arr.length-1)`